# Heartbeat lost in HDP cluster

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, heartbeat

I am using 10 nodes HDP cluster, out of 10 one of the node was getting restarted within few hours, As suggested by Linux admin we had restaged that particular node. This node consists of Snamenode, one of the zookeeper server and hbase master.

After restaging entire cluster went down, after restaging  of one node, the entire cluster should not get affected right? but instead of that I was getting heartbeat lost from all of the nodes except Master node.

Comment: Did you install through Ambari? If yes, have you checked the Ambari agents are still running?

Comment: yes I have installed through ambari.. Everything is fine on the nodes.

Comment: How to add the restaged node back to cluster? Do I need to reinstall everything .. In ambari I did not get an option to add a node..

Comment: I am facing the same issue, what is the solution ...

Comment: the clock timing was not in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the clock timing was not in sync on one of the node.